# Win32 Application with unlimited access to memory

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

i want to create Win32 application (in C/C++), that will have unlimited access to system memory. I just want to know if is it possible, and if it is, i want to know the shortest possible way to create that application. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of memory? random access memory?

Comment: Yes, random access memory.

Comment: What do  you mean by "access"? Are you referring to being able to read the data inside the ram? Or are you referring to being able to allocate all the ram for your Win32 application?

Comment: Read (or write) memory at any location.

Comment: that would be a huge security risk.

Comment: @DanielA.White yes, it would. But i want to experiment with it on my own computer, where i have full control (i mean administrative rights), so...

Comment: @SmaxSmaxović - the only way this is possible is in kernel land, for which you'd have to write a kernel module or device driver. Attempting to access unmapped memory, even as a system administrator, will cause a segmentation fault, causing your program to crash.

Comment: The closest thing you are going to find is [ReadProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680553%28VS.85%29.aspx) and its sister function [WriteProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681674(v=vs.85).aspx). These functions allow you to read and write the memory of a given process. Anything better then this, you'll need to possibly design a Windows device driver for. Note that ReadProcessMemory and WriteProcessMemory both require PROCESS_VM_READ and/or PROCESS_VM_WRITE access

Comment: You'll have to write a kernel driver.  User-mode applications (by their very nature) are not allowed to read memory belonging to other applications.  In addition, not all parts of the address space for a particular application are necessarily in RAM; some parts could be paged out.

Comment: @slugonamission I want to achieve that, i want to create application, that can access these parts of memory without segfault, so with rights from OS.

Comment: @SmaxSmaxović - in which case, you'll have to download the Windows Driver Development Kit (DDK). You can't easily show a form from it though (you can, but it gets sandboxed on its own virtual desktop, I've seen it happen once :S ). Note that this is not easy in the slightest. Why exactly do you want to do this?

Comment: @slugonamission I want this for my experiments, just for "playing" I know about WDDK, but I'm searching for another way.

Comment: @SmaxSmaxović You are missing the point. There is no other way. This is how the Windows operating system works. You are either going to use WDDK or you are going to have to write your own operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to access the system memory is from a kernel mode driver. So, if you are going to do this, you'll have to write such a thing.

Comment: This, along with all the comments on the question, overlooks the key point that kernel code can do pretty much *anything* on the system.  Including removing the barriers which prevent user-mode processes from accessing pages from other processes.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, I overlooked that. It's a pretty far out idea though.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a kernel driver to change the page table mappings.  Once the memory is mapped into your process's address space, a user-mode process could then access it.  Of course, this comes with a severe warning -- **an application with access to kernel memory areas could easily destabilize your system or worse.**  Of course the changes should be done in cooperation with the virtual memory manager by using its APIs and not changing the mappings directly, otherwise kernel memory management is likely to get very confused when its entries aren't in the locations it expected.

There is nothing preventing user-mode applications from accessing memory belonging to other processes, except that the existing kernel code doesn't provide such access, except in very limited cases.  For example, file mappings already DO use shared memory and give user-mode processes access to kernel-owned pages (owned by the disk cache).

Note that the virtual address would still not match the physical address, and only kernel code can use physical addresses directly.  So using this for things like DMA would be difficult.

(I know of a kernel driver that does this for I/O ports -- giveio.sys, which is often used by hardware monitoring software.  Not sure whether it can be used for memory page access or you'd need to find a different one/write your own.  On linux, there is a widely-available kernel module that gives user code access to all memory, via the `/dev/kmem` device.  Which is a good example that this doesn't necessarily break security, since `/dev/kmem` checks for superuser rights on the requesting process, and a Windows driver can do approximately the same.)

The shortest way is undoubtedly to find an existing driver that exposes ioctls for this.  At that point the user-mode application only needs to install and load a driver, then use its ioctls to map the pages you want into your process.  User-mode APIs for managing drivers and devices (with admin rights of course) are well-documented.